# Conical hull of two circles

Tags: convex-analysis

Let $X=A\cup B$ with $A$ and $B$ circles of radius $1$, parallels to the plane $XZ$ that lie in $(0,1,0)$ and $(0,-1,0)$ respectively.

I'm asked to characterize the $cone(X)$, the conical hull of $X$. The definition can be found here [Conical Hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conical_combination#Conical_hull)

I'm suggested to use polar coordinates.

I think that the solution of this problem is all the open upper semispace plus the y axis. But I don't know how to prove formally and I don't know why I am suggested to use polar coordinates. Maybe I have characterize $X$ analytically and then transform it into polar coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

Answer is entire $R^3$.

Hint: Try to show that Conic hull of $X$ contains three axis X,Y and Z. Thus since Conic hull is always convex it has to contains entire space.

Comment: Is this right? I mean, how can u create any point wich the form (x,y,z) with z<0 if both A and B are over the plane z=0.

Comment: @Lecter As I understand your question you have two circles with radius $1$ parallel to paln xz and centered those two points. In this case points like $(0,1,-1)$ and $(0,-1,-1)$ living on them.  If this not what you meant then I didn't get your question.